Creating & styling a layer and saving an image with it in the modeller
I want to set a layer style in the modeller and afterwards export the map to an image.
For that I created a simple layout with just a map and a simple model that sets a style and exports a print layout to an image.
QGIS canvas

The layout

The model

Log
QGIS version: 3.36.2-Maidenhead
Qt version: 5.15.13
Python version: 3.12.3
GDAL version: 3.8.5
GEOS version: 3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.4.0, March 1st, 2024
PDAL version: 2.7.1 (git-version: Release)
Algorithm started at: 2024-05-18T13:00:53
Algorithm 'geometry_by_expression' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'extent' : '-188.895000000,188.895000000,-220.320593172,214.054693172 [EPSG:4326]', 'random_points' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

Successfully exported layout to /tmp/processing_jrnSAr/021f603f9ffe43abb38f14d1c4fa134f/OUTPUT.png
Model processed OK. Executed 3 algorithms total in 0.61s.
Execution completed in 0.63 seconds
Results:
  random_points: Random_points_19eaec9f_3c44_45f5_95ae_62f0fa50df2c

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'geometry_by_expression' finished

Resulting image
There is an image file OUTPUT.png exported to Processing's temporary output directory. The image does not the layer that was created and styled in the modeller.

What the map should look like in the exported image


How can I export a print layout after creating a layer and setting its style in the QGIS modeller?
Here is a zip with a project, model and layout: http://0x0.st/XPaK.zip

The error seems to be caused by my image output name. With no explicit output, there is no error. The result does not show the layer in the new style though.

In QGIS version: 3.36.2-Maidenhead it generates the same error but the layout is printed with the style updated correctly.

Argh, my test example was too simple: In reality I create a new layer as part of the model and set the style on that. Printing this did not use the newly set style even in 3.36.2. I tested it with a buffer. I will update the question later. Sorry for failing the test example :]

I updated the question and included a project, model and layout to test. It is probably a race condition, the output might appear by sheer luck if adding the layer to the project happens fast enough before the layout export happens.

I first tried using Load layer into project before the export thinking that it didn't work because the created layer wasn't registered in a way the layout manager can use, but it didn't help. You can see what I found that does work below. It might be possible to make it work another way that doesn't require to specify each wanted layer.

You can set the layers to be assigned to the map item of the layout in the advanced parameters. You need to select both layers otherwise only either one will be displayed.


This should give the expected result:

